# Adding values to a multiple select with jQuery's select2

Tags: jquery, selection, jquery-select2, multiple-select, multipleselection

I'm using the [`select2`](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) jQuery plugin on a `<select>` with `multiple="multiple"`. I need to *add* values to the selected list (i.e. not to all the options, but to the selected options, without adding a new option).

I know I can set the selected options with [this](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#programmatic):

```
$("#the_select").select2("val", "the_option_value");
```

Or, for multiple selections:

```
$("#the_select").select2("val", ["an_option_value","another_option_value"]);
```

However, is there a way I can add *selected options* to the list (i.e. make an option selected) without removing the others?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You should be able to use this:

```
$("#the_select").append($('<option>', {value:"NEWVAL", text: "New Option Text"}));
```

It will append the new option item to the end of the list.

HTH

**Edit**

Take 2 :) -  I tried this in chrome dev tools over on the select2 page.  It works (I added "WA" and `Washington` appeared.

```
var selectedItems = $("#the_select").select2("val");
selectedItems.push("NEWITEMVAL");   // I used "WA" here to test.
$("#the_select").select2("val", selectedItems);
```

Or as a one liner:

```
$("#the_select").select2("val", $("#the_select").select2("val").concat("NEWITEMVAL"));
```

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I don't want to add an option, I want to select an option. Also, I doubt that this would work without re-initializing the select2 plugin.

Comment: Why the down vote?  You did state 'I need to add values to the selected list.' :-)  And it does work without reinitialising the plugin.  Try it.

Comment: _Selected_, not _select_. Also, if you would've looked at the code, you'd see that I was changing the value (thus the selected onces) and not the options of the select. It might work, it doesn't do what I asked, so it isn't an answer to my question. I'll rephrase it to make it more clear.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking. But is there a command for `select2` to do this, so that I don't need three lines?

Comment: Great - that's better!  There doesn't seem to be anything on select2 to do this -  (https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/blob/master/select2.js#L3011).  You could always extend the plugin yourself if you really wanted to.

Comment: I tried this and it wont add selected value instead changed all value to the first element of the array. :(

Comment: @SeanKenny you are the man bro don't ever let anybody tell you otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

This is how i do it:

```
      $("#the-select")
        .val($("#the-select")
          .val()
          .concat([array_of_existing_values]));
      $("#the-select")
        .trigger("change");
```

HTH